# Expression/term for space between door and floor/wall

Tags: expressions, terminology

Let's say smoke is escaping through a close door. It would be escaping through the space between the door and the floor or the wall, or perhaps between door and the jamb. Is there a term for that? Or is there an expression for that (perhaps: smoke seeping through the door? but that would suggest that it goes through door, rather than the space between the door and the floor or jamb).

Comment: As you say, smoke does not seep through the door. It seeps through the *doorway*. And it *seeps* because the door itself is closed. If it were open, then smoke would *pour* or *billow* through the doorway.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, but despite the door being closed, the smoke still escapes through the gaps, because the door is not airtight. Is there an expression for that?

Comment: In contradiction to an earlier comment, I would completely understand what *smoke coming **through** the door* meant. It's used on a fairly regular basis, in my experience. It's not *literally* true, but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

**Door gap** is the general name for all of the gaps around the door.

> The best method for measuring **door gap dimensions** is to use a tool of the appropriate thickness that can be inserted  between  the  door  frame  and  door,  **the  door  and the floor**, and between opposing vertical edges (aka, meeting stiles) of paired doors.  ([Doorgapgauge.com](http://www.doorgapgauge.com/articles/MeasuringDoorGaps180417.pdf), emphasis added)

At [idighardware.com](https://idighardware.com/2016/08/wwyd-clearance-vs-undercut/), the [sdi fact file](https://www.steeldoor.org/pdf/SDI%20Fact%20File.pdf) is quoted, calling the gap at the floor

> **FLOOR CLEARANCE**:  The distance between the bottom of the door and the top of the material directly below the door. This varies with applications, such as concrete, any floor covering and/or a threshold.
> [image: floor clearance]

This gap is also called **bottom clearance**, and the top gap is called **head clearance**, while the side gaps are called **stile clearances** at [taylordoors.com](https://www.taylorsdoors.com.au/resources/frames/common-terms-frames).

To class them all together, you could say "The smoke is seeping through the **door gaps**."

Comment: I have no idea why someone downvoted your answer. Door gap and door clearance are just right. +1

Comment: Consider *crack*.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything shorter than a long  phrase:

- smoke stream/ing/ed/ in through the chinks of the door where it meets the frame.